# Forward search RestFB

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using RestFB to search multiple terms on Facebook. I am using following code to achieve that.

```
Connection<Post> publicSearch = publicOnlyFacebookClient
            .fetchConnection(
                    "search",
                    Post.class,
                    Parameter.with("since",
                            DateFormatter.stringToDate("2013-01-01")),
                    Parameter.with("q", "apple OR oranges"),
                    Parameter.with("type", "post"));
```

I have two questions.

1. Is this the correct way of using OR
2. I observed, even when I have mentioned "since" I get results in decreasing order in timestamp. The results start from NOW and go backwords. Is there a method to start getting methods in forward manner (something like twitter streaming API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use the `|` character for OR (e.g `apple | oranges`)
2. Graph API always returns the latest results first, there are no parameters to control that. To work around this you could implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares the `Post` class by time and sort the result `List` using [Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)